# Retrieve all documents from a view

Tags: 2013, document-library, view, caml

We have a document library with views created based on a column. This views have documents spread out to different folders. How can i retrieve all the documents in a particular view using CAML query or any other approach programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Following code

```
          SPList List = _site.Lists.TryGetList("ListName");
          SPView view = List.Views["Name"];
          SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
          query.Query = view.Query;
          query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";                        
          SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Candidates");
                        SPQuery oquery = new SPQuery();

                        oquery.Query = " <Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='CandidateName' /></IsNotNull></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>";
                        SPListItemCollection coll = list.GetItems(oquery);
                        DataTable dt = coll.GetDataTable();
                        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            oGridView.DataSource = dt;
                            oGridView.DataBind();
                        }
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    }
                }
```